# v-date-picker not opening on desired month

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuetify.js

I'm working with a v-date-picker in my vue.js application. I'm trying to get it to open on a specific month. I set the min prop to a certain date in order to disable any date before the min date. If this min date is on a future month, it would be nice if the date picker would open on that month instead of the current month. I'm not able to get it to do this.

There is this discussion:

https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/113

...which says that there is a bug in the v-date-picker for setting the month it opens on, but none of the solutions or work arounds work for me.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example of your code?

Comment: Would need to see the code. Take a look at this article for guidelines on providing a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for the link Tanner. I've simplified the code at the link. I tried to provide the code on fiddle but couldn't reproduce the problem (instead the min prop doesn't work), but you can see my code if you go to 35.232.230.0:81/code. Sorry for the round-about way of posting this.

Answer (score 0):

use "show-current" attribute you can open your calendar with the desired date.      `<v-date-picker v-model="month1" show-current="2013-18" type="month"></v-date-picker>`
check this link.
https://codepen.io/neha-shivhare/pen/ZEXXMdE?editors=101

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).